# Display Console.ReadLine() in switch statement

Tags: c#

I'm building console applications to sharpen my c# skills. I'm having two issues that I can't seem to find online.

**Issue 1:** I want to display whatever the user inputs in the output (user enters a numeric value.. when the program runs and displays an answer, I want the user input to be displayed as well)..

**Issue 2:** Currently you have to press the enter key twice to continue after the first input. Is there a way to only have to press the enter key once?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the existing code (I'll include both classes just incase you need the second for some reason):

```
namespace StaticDemo {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string selection = string.Empty;
            while (selection != "q" && selection != "Q")
            {
                Console.Write("Enter C)elsius to Fahrentheit or F(ahrenheit to Celsius or Q(uit. \nSelect C, F, or Q then press the enter key twice to continue: ");
                selection = Console.ReadLine();

                double fahrenheit = 0, celsius = 0;
                string line = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (selection)
                {

                    case "C":
                    case "c":
                        Console.Write("Please enter the Celsius temperature that you want converted to a Fahrenheit temperature: ");
                        fahrenheit = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine($"The temperature you provided in celsius: {line}, would be: {fahrenheit} in fahrentheit");
                        break;

                    case "F":
                    case "f":
                        Console.Write("Please enter the Farentheit temperature that you want converted to a Celsius temperature: ");
                        celsius = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine($"The temperature you provided in Fahrentheit: {line}, would be: {celsius} in celsius");
                        break;

                    case "Q":
                    case "q":
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter C F or a Q, Moron!");
                        break;

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    } }
```

The second class code is below if you need it for whatever reason:

```
namespace StaticDemo
{
    class TemperatureConverter
    {
        public static double CelsiusToFahrenheit(string tempCelsius)
        {
            double celcius = double.Parse(tempCelsius);
            double fahrenheit = (celcius * 9 / 5) + 32;
            return fahrenheit;
        }
        public static double FahrenheitToCelsius(string tempFahrenheit)
        {
            double fahrenheit = double.Parse(tempFahrenheit);
            double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
            return celsius;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you have two readline calls in your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is useless and it is the reason for the two input required to process the choice

```
 string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

You have already read the selection variable two lines up.

To get the value for the temperature provided by the user, you need to get the input without passing it directly to the conversion class

```
  Console.Write("Please enter the Celsius temperature that you want converted to a Fahrenheit temperature: ");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  fahrenheit = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(input);
  Console.WriteLine($"The temperature you provided in Celsius: {input}, would be: {celsius} in Fahrenheit");
```

Of course the same applies to the other block of code that converts a Fahrenheit to Celsius. Notice also that I think you have inverted the message.

Comment: Steve, thanks so much! First. you were right about displaying the wrong Fahrenheit message when selecting F. I just copy pasted and forgot to switch the method. Everything that you suggested worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the user input twice basically.

```
Console.Write("Enter C)elsius to Fahrentheit or F(ahrenheit to Celsius or Q(uit. \nSelect C, F, or Q then press the enter key twice to continue: ");
selection = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the temperature that you want converted: ");
string tempToConvert = Console.ReadLine();

switch (selection)
{
    case "C":                      
        fahrenheit = TemperatureConverter.CelsiusToFahrenheit(Console.ReadLine());
                     Console.WriteLine($"The temperature you provided in celsius: {tempToConvert }, would be: {fahrenheit} in fahrentheit");
                     break;
```

Consider using ToUpper or ToLower on user inputs so you don't have to worry about the formatting of the input when you make your cases.

Comment: Oh, very nice! I never knew that! Very useful! Thank you very much, Sam!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
selection = Console.ReadLine();
```

to

```
selection = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadKey());
```

also i think after making the above change you do not need this line.

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks I have read it , i guess you are referring to the formatting of code snippets.. made some modifications .. let me know how it looks now..

Answer (score 0):

It is because of line

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

Change it to

```
string line;
```

I think you previously wanted that line to read value to convert.